# SIP Express Router- MaxFwd Module

Tags: sip

How can I change Max_Forward headers value in SIP request? 
I'm using SER and two xlite sipphones,and I want to check MaxFwd module.

Comment: +1 to viraptor. Can you specify the exact problem?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot (actually shouldn't) change that header anywhere else than on the client. Every proxy should subtract one from the value and pass it to the next hop. Check `x-lite` configuration if the default value is too small for your architecture.

You should never change the value on the way, otherwise you can cause endless loops (or at least loops until the size of the packet crosses the udp limit boundary).